# Is Session id will be same for different client in Single instance context mode in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-sessions

Is Session id will be same for different client in Single instance context mode in WCF?

Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I know answer is No, session id will be different but variable values will be shared. I tried it.

But it will be great if some one can explain how server is able to share data while having different session id for different client.